# How to simulate home automation system?

Tags: simulation

I am trying to make home automation system. Basically it consists of lights and fans connected through a relay to an arduino which is connected to internet. I have to switch them on and off by an application if no one is present in the house which is known by placing IR sensors.
So i want sensors,arduino,relay.

How to simulate the circuit working in virtual environment as it is costly to buy hardware and program? Is there any tool to do so?

Comment: What information do you want to get out of your simulation?

Comment: Trying to use a resource-constrained classic Arduino with anything Internet is so fundamentally cost, time and difficulty inefficient that the simulation question goes out the window.  But even with a good setup, you will learn more with real hardware, which is quite inexpensive compared to the time you will spend.  The actual role for something like simulation is if you want to have an automated test as part of a continuous integration software process, and often the easiest way to do that is to cross compile your embedded firmware with I/O wrappers to run on your build server.

Answer (score 2):

**Software and hardware**

There are two aspects of your design to be tested: software and hardware. We can further break the hardware down into the micro-controller and board (including the power-supply, USB and I/O pins) that come on the Arduino board and everything else - the PIR, lamps and relays.

**Test, correct, retest**

You can run a simulation by loading your test code onto the micro controller board, use a switch or button for the PIRs and LEDs for the lamps and relays. Draw up a test plan to function test each of your design requirements and then execute your plan. Correct any errors and retest until all is correct.

This will give you good confidence on those aspects of your system. Then you can spend the rest of the budget on your sensors and relays with low risk of failure.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question about the simulation to be a bit vague. What would be your purpose with said simulation?

What I am getting at is, if you would set up a virtual simulation, you would probably just set up exact/optimal parameters taken from your hardwares datasheets. Meaning that if the virtual person walks in the range of the IR sensor the relay switches. Simply the trivial behaviour you would expect from your design. And what information would this give you?

To further elaborate, I personally do not know of any virtual environment software that gives you the possibility to set up this simulation. However I have seen software for simulating industrial environments (robots/workflow). In such a program you would possibly be able to simulate something close to what you are asking for. However these arent freeware, and as your main purpose of simulation seems to be to keep costs down these industrial softwares arent for you.

Bottom line I am having trouble understanding what you want to achieve with a simulation. My suggestion if you are worried about costs is to make some cheap prototype with cheap parts (shorter ranges etc) and source your parts from China. I am certain that you will be able to make some sort of working prototype for only a few dollars. And then you can just upgrade the project from there.

Comment: @jeevansaijinne Okay, so you simply want an illustration of your project plan? I think your original question is way to vague on describing your purpose of "simulating" your system. As 'transistors' answer is additional proof of, most people here are in the mindset of helping you design your project. It seems like you are asking of good software to do 3D visualizations if your project and then I would argue that the Electrical Engineering stack is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: (this was a response to a comment by OP that now seems to have been deleted.)